# Sending an email from an address that is only forwarding to my current address

Tags: gmail

All in Gmail. I have one address, `123@`, that is forwarding to another address, `abc@`.

Having lost access to the `123` address is there a way to still reply to mail sent to `123` as if it is coming from the `123` address not the `abc` that I currently use?

Answer (score 1):

Check Gmail Settings --> Accounts and Import.

From there, "Add another email address you own".  I don't believe you need to be able to log into your @123 email since any verification emails are being forwarded back to you already.

Then, below that setting choose "Reply from the same address the message was sent to".

Once it's set up, you can A) choose to send as either @123 or @abc when composing and B) easily reply to messages as @123 when the came is as to @123 by just clicking standard "reply" button.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you have forwarded all your mails from 123@ to abc@. Now don't have access to 123@ and wanted to send mail from abc@ with from address as @123.

For the above you can send mail from abc@ having from address as 123@ and it will be delivered as you expect